# Photoshop Automation (Executing script through button panel in photoshop)

Tags: javascript, automation, photoshop

I'm writing a .Net application that utilises Photoshop. Any version of Photoshop from 'CS2 or later is acceptable, but I don't know which version any particular client will have. which photoshop version should use in installation package? What to do which support all cs2 to cs5 photoshop version

Comment: This looks off-topic to me.  At very least, show what you have tried so far and state what is working and what isn't.

Comment: @Jonathan I have add this code and this is perfectly working...but when I add photoshop cs3 reference (com object library) it is only working in cs2 not in cs3 how can I add multiple photoshop reference at the same time....or any other ideaPublic Class Form1
    Dim PhotoshopApp As Photoshop.Application
    Dim photoshopDoc As Photoshop.Document
    Dim curLayer As Photoshop.ArtLayer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("E:\SuperSoft.jsx")
    End Sub
End Class